# Cannot render HillbillyCascade on SPO365 Classic

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I am using SPO365 in Classic Mode to render cascading dropdowns on a document library edit form.  I am trying to use Hillbilly Cascade to achieve this functionality, but for some reason I keep getting an Uncaught TypeError thrown at me noting that HillbillyCascade is not a function.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?  Note, that I am using bootstrap in the masterpage for Classic Experience.

Has anyone known of any issues experienced with bootstrap and Hillbilly Cascade?

Code is as follows:

```
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../SiteAssets/HillbillyCascade.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var cascadeArray = new Array();

        cascadeArray.push({
            parentFormField: "POC", //Display name on form of field from parent list
            childList: "delParentTask", //List name of child list
            childLookupField: "Title", //Internal field name in Child List used in lookup
            childFormField: "Task Number", //Display name on form of the child field
            parentFieldInChildList: "delPOC", //Internal field name in Child List of the parent field
            firstOptionText: "< Select the Task Number >"
        });

        cascadeArray.push({
            parentFormField: "Task Number", //Display name on form of field from parent list
            childList: "delChildTaskName", //List name of child list
            childLookupField: "Title", //Internal field name in Child List used in lookup
            childFormField: "Task Name", //Display name on form of the child field
            parentFieldInChildList: "taskNumber", //Internal field name in Child List of the parent field
            firstOptionText: "< Select a Task Name >"
        });


        $().HillbillyCascade(cascadeArray);

    });


</script>
```

It's been loaded on the EditForm with a Script Editor. All url paths are correct; I can see that the Hillbilly Cascade script loads.

Error is as follows:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).HillbillyCascade is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (EditForm.aspx:696)

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to use below code in place of `document.ready()`:

   ```
    function runAfterEverythingElse(){
       // your code
    }

    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterEverythingElse");
   ```
2. Also check if you are adding jQuery file multiple times in your page or not?

In that case you have to use "jQuery noConflict()".

Comment: Thanks. I figured it was jQuery being loaded twice and used no conflict however that didn’t seem to work. I’ll look into it more and get back to you. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Welcome. Try to debug using browser console by setting breakpoint at that line.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have upload the "HillbillyCascade.js" file into Site Assets library and check in.

If it still not works, try to reference the js file like this.

```
<script src="/sites/lz/SiteAssets/HillbillyCascade.js"></script>
```